# Android things on raspberry - Send push notification from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I'm making a POC in which I'm sending a notification from firebase console to the raspberry running android things.

This worked well when the code was on a smartphone, and when I moved it to the raspberry, nothing works anymore. I can see in the raspberry console (in Android Studio) that the notification is somewhat seen by the rpi3, but the onMessageReceived is not triggered...

Here is some code:

My manifest:

```
<service
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

The subscribing:

```
private void subscribeToPushService() {
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");

    Log.d("AndroidBash", "Subscribed");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Subscribed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
}
```

The service:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMessageService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "NOTIF");
    }
}
```

And finally the notification I send with the firebase console, I really don't understand where I messed up, the package name seems ok...

Thx for reading!

[image: Firebase console notification]

Comment: "I can see in the raspberry console (in Android Studio) that the notification is somewhat seen by the rpi3..." <-- can you describe what this means in a bit more detail, or add the log messages to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems [DP5](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html#developer_preview_5) of Android Things still didn't support Firebase Notifications (from [Official Overview](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/index.html)):

> Android Things supports a subset of the Google APIs for Android. The
> following table breaks down API support in Android Things:
>
> Unavailable APIs:
>
> AdMob
>
> Android Pay
>
> Drive
>
> Firebase App Indexing
>
> Firebase Authentication
>
> Firebase Dynamic Links
>
> Firebase Invites
>
> [**Firebase Notifications**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/)
>
> Play Games
>
> Sign-In

Comment: Firebase Cloud messaging seems to be supported now: https://developer.android.com/things/get-started/google-services

Comment: @nicolas Seems you are right. I will check and update the answer.